# Debugging local Symfony server doesn't work in all places

Tags: php, symfony, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm to run my Symfony application locally. In order to debug, I installed Xdebug as well as the corresponding helper extension for Chrome.

Debugging in general works. For example, if I put a breakpoint in the `doDispatch()` function inside of the Symfony class `Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher` and start my server, the breakpoint triggers and I can step through the code.

However, that very same breakpoint is being ignored, when I call the method through my own code. Any breakpoint I put into my own controllers/services isn't recognized either, even though there is a checkmark on the breakpoints once the server starts.

This is what I've added to my `php.ini`:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time = 3600
xdebug.remote_enable = 0
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000

xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
```

This is my server output on startup:

```
/usr/bin/php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 /home/.../bin/console server:run

 [OK] Server listening on http://127.0.0.1:8001                                 

 // Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I've tried both `localhost:8000` as well as `127.0.0.1:8001` for debugging, but both of them don't trigger my breakpoints.

FYI, I did start listening for PHP debug connections in PhpStorm and started debugging in the browser extension.

I'm using PHP version 7.3.1 and the newest beta version of Xdebug.

`xdebug.log` after hitting a route whose controller had a breakpoint in it:

```
[28601] Log opened at 2019-01-29 15:54:28
[28601] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[28601] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[28601] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[28601] W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000. :-|
[28601] I: Connected to client. :-)
[28601] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/.../bin/console" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.3.1" protocol_version="1.0" appid="28601" idekey="11916"><engine version="2.7.0beta1"><![CDATA[Xd$
[28601]
[28601] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- status -i 5
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- step_into -i 6
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="6" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///home/.../bin/console" lineno="9"></xdebug:message></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///home/.../src/Controller/HostController.php -n 30
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="286010001"></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- stack_get -i 8
[28601] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="8"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///home/.../bin/console" lineno="9"></stack></response>
[28601]
[28601] <- run -i 9
```

Comment: How exactly do you call `doDispatch` in your own code? Have you made sure that it **really** hits the same method?

Comment: yes, I'm certain that the method is being called, because I have an event subscriber that triggers after I press a button. Furthermore, I also tried breakpoints in more direct places like my controllers, none of them being triggered.

Comment: What happens if you enable "Break at first line"? Maybe path mappings got screwed up?

Comment: "break at first line" triggers correctly.

Comment: And can you step through all of your code afterwards?

Comment: I've stepped through multiple files after that initial breakpoint, so I assume it works yes. To me it looks like a problem with the client side debug configuration, but I don't know what exactly.

Comment: Hard to say anything concrete without knowing the actual setup. But 1) Maybe "calling through my code" creates separate request? Try increasing max debug connections from default 1 to 3. 2) Path mappings could be the issue (especially if there is a symlinks involved). PhpStorm works with file paths as is ... but Xdebug will use final/resolved paths. 3) Collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session, it may give you some hints. if not, may need to enable extra logging on IDE side as well.

Comment: @LazyOne I've added my xdebug.log for unsuccessful debug attemps

Comment: The log looks incomplete (debug session is still in process?)... Since I'm not a Symfony user .. I do not know it's lifecycle  and how it may call your code / why it should be different. But have a look at #1 in my prev comment and see if it will make any diff.  You can also enable logs on IDE side -- may tell if there is some path mappings issue or what not: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs

Comment: Another thought: not every breakpoint can be hit (e.g. in multiline statement the actual breakpoint will be somewhere in the middle). I also suggest to try PHP 7.2 and Xdebug stable 2.6 -- just in case there are any issues in beta version (including PHP and OPCache).